# "The target server failed to respond" when using HttpSolrServer

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, httpclient

`http://localhost:8080/solr` works well in my browser and there is no error in the console of tomcat when I start it.

my code is：

```
    public static void index() throws SolrServerException, IOException {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/solr";
        HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(url);
        SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
        doc.addField("id", "1");
        doc.addField("name", "name");
        doc.addField("content", "cold today");
        server.add(doc);
        server.commit();
    }
```

when I run the code,there is nothing printed in the console of tomcat and I get 
`Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond` instead.
the full failure trace is:

```
    org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://localhost:8080/solr
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:507)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:199)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:118)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:116)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:102)
        at com.cc.solr.SolrDemo.index(SolrDemo.java:21)
        at com.cc.solr.TestSolrDemo.testIndex(TestSolrDemo.java:16)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:395)
        ... 29 more
```

I think here is something wrong in my computer but I can not figure out.

I have tried `solr 4.6.0` and `solr 4.7.2`,both of them failed.
It fails when running this code：
`final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);`
in `HttpSolrServer.java(line number 395 in 4.7.2)`

But when I copied the project to my roommate's computer ,it worked fine.

It's very wierd.It seems that the request is successfully accepted by server  and if I change my code like：

```
    public static void index() throws SolrServerException, IOException {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/solr";
        HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(url);
        server.setSoTimeout(10000); 
        SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
        doc.addField("id", "3");
        doc.addField("name", "name3");
        doc.addField("content", "cold today3");
        try{
        server.add(doc);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); //time out
        }
        server.commit();
    }
```

It still prints exception message but it works...

Comment: Did you forget to specify the collection / core in the url? I.e.: http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1 or http://localhost:8080/solr/core0

Comment: @D_K I think there is something wrong in my computer,I copy the project and the webapps to my roommate's computer and it works fine.

Comment: still, for the code to work end-to-end, I believe you need to specify the collection or core in the url. Have you tried that on your computer?

Comment: It's not necessary.The base url is correct.I try to catch the exception of `server.add(doc);`.There is still exception message but it works.So wierd. @D_K

Comment: does the document get added in the index?

Comment: Yes and I can get result through `HttpSolrServer.query` which works fine without any exception. @D_K

Comment: is the same err message present for  server.add(doc);  on your roommate's computer?

Comment: no,it works just fine without any error message.@D_K

Comment: got it. So must be a hardware / network problem.

Comment: Yes,I replaced `HttpClient` with another version.I changed my jdk version and Tomcat version.But it still remains the same.It seems nothing wrong with software.@D_K

Comment: @fairjm, did you find any solution?. bcoz I too facing this problem.